# Can't get an NSString out of a JSON object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I'm grabbing an element from an NSMutableDictionary, which was created by getting the data back from an NSURLSessionDataTask and using NSJSONSerialization to deserialize it like so:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:&error];
```

So after returning the JSON, I cache it in an NSCache and then when I pick it up again to use, I try to get an element that seems to show up as an NSNumber:

```
NSString *hopefullyAString = [[NSNumber numberWithLong:settings[@"hopefullyAString"] stringValue]];
```

Now I set my breakpoint and this is what I plug into the console:

```
(lldb) po labs(hopefullyAString.longValue)
error: property 'longValue' not found on object of type 'NSString *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po [hopefullyAString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
false
```

Which is weird because on one hand I can't get the longValue of an NSString, but apparently, the so called string is not an NSString. What is going on?

Ultimately, this is what I want:

```
anotherString = [anotherString stringByAppendingString:hopefullyAString];
```

But when I plug it in, I get an error:

```
(lldb) po queryParams = [anotherString stringByAppendingString:hopefullyAString]
2015-09-28 11:22:09.946 SomeApp[826:265400] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000004cfa73
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

And if I try to play through the breakpoint (appending the strings):

```
2015-09-28 11:23:41.804 SomeApp[826:265400] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000004cfa73
 2015-09-28 11:23:41.806 SomeApp[826:267251] XPC connection interrupted
2015-09-28 11:23:41.809 SomeApp[826:265400] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000004cfa73'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182154f5c 0x196c57f80 0x18215bc6c 0x182158c14 0x18205cdcc 0x182fac88c 0x1000db8d4 0x1000db670 0x1000d390c 0x1879ed67c 0x1879ed7d4 0x1879dd3d4 0x1879f2364 0x187793a90 0x1876a700c 0x186eadf14 0x186ea8b20 0x186ea89e0 0x186ea807c 0x186ea7dd0 0x186ea14bc 0x18210bc30 0x1821099d4 0x182109e04 0x182038dc0 0x18d18c088 0x187712f60 0x1000d5f6c 0x1974828b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I know it's probably something minor that I'm not understanding, so thanks ahead of time.

EDIT 1: Forgot to mention... I'm using Xcode 7, not sure if that's related, but the same code was working a few weeks ago when I was back on Xcode 6.

Comment: is settings a dictionary ?

Comment: Try: `id hopefullyAString = settings[@"hopefullyAString"]; NSLog("Type %@", [hopefullyAString class]);` It should log the type of the value for that key, which will help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Yeah settings was a dictionary - thanks, I tried that... Now it's working. Wish it was a coding fix, but I guess if you have an outstanding update to Xcode, take it ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message in the debugger is because you are telling it that `hopefullyAString` is a string and it trusts that you are telling it the truth and then trying to call a method that doesn't exist on `NSString`.

The second debugger command is false because now it is actually checking itself if it is an `NSString` and finding that it isn't.

Your other errors are because you are passing an `NSNumber` (what your `hopefullyAString` actually is) to a method that takes an `NSString`.

Your block of code where you are assigning `hopefullyAString` isn't valid syntax and won't compile so it is hard to say what you what you specifically need to change, but you shouldn't be passing an objc object to `numberWithLong` anyway.

Comment: NSString *hopefullyAString = [[NSNumber numberWithLong:settings[@"hopefullyAString"] stringValue]]; 

That's valid though - it compiles - stringValue of an NSNumber is valid. I've also tried it with

    NSString *hopefullyAString = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%ld", settings[@"hopefullyAString"]];

Comment: Taking the string value of an `NSNumber` is valid but you have your `]` is in the wrong place so your snippet specifically won't compile.  But the main point is that `settings[@"hopefullyAString"]` can't return a `long` so passing it to `numberWithLong` is wrong either way.

Comment: That's really strange... You're right about the location of my bracket but I was cleaning and then building and running it on my phone and it was "compiling" but never caught the error. Just upgraded my xcode command line tools and restarted my computer and switched the bracket location, and now it works. Not sure what exactly fixed it, but it seems that it was a bug in Xcode that was fixed with the last Xcode command tools update, or my mac was in a weird state.

Answer (score 1):

> error: property 'longValue' not found on object of type 'NSString *'

This is unsurprising: [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/) doesn't have a `longValue` property. There's a `longLongValue` property, however, and I expect that this is what you were thinking of.

> -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000004cfa73

In this case the problem is with `anotherString`, which doesn't seem to point to a valid instance of `NSString`. Did you properly initialize `anotherString`? You should do something like this:

```
NSString *anotherString = @"Some string."
anotherString = [anotherString stringByAppendingString:hopefullyAString];
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000004cfa73'

Yes, terminating the app is what usually happens when an exception is thrown. Fix your code and the exception will go away. The message, however, tells you that you're trying to send the `-length` message to an instance of `NSNumber`, which doesn't have a `-length` method. I'd guess that the object in `hopefullyAString` is represented as a number rather than a string in the JSON file, so you get a number back when it's deserialized.

Comment: Yeah you're also right, I got an NSNumber back, which is why I was trying to convert it to an NSString either with stringWithFormat or getting the stringValue of the NSNumber... Seems like it was an issue with Xcode itself and the new update patched the bug.